# All conjugacy classes of $\operatorname{SL}_2 \mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

For an odd prime $p$, is the number of the conjugacy classes of $\operatorname{SL}_2 \mathbb{F}_p$ p+4 ?

I showed a partial result:

Let $A$ be a matrix.
Consider its characteristic polynomial $p$.
Then over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, $p$ has roots.
Write it $\xi, \zeta$.
Then since the determinant is $1$, we have that $\zeta = \xi ^{-1}$.
And since the trace is in $\mathbb{F}_p$, we have that $\xi + \xi ^{-1} \in \mathbb{F}_p$.
Thus $(\xi^{p-1} - 1)(\xi ^{p+1} - 1)=0$

1. The case that $\xi = \pm 1$.
   In this case we have that $A = \pm \left( \begin{matrix}1 & * \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$.
   (6 matrices are in this case.)
2. The case that $\xi \not= \pm 1$ and $\xi^{p-1} = 1$.
   In this case $\xi \in \mathbb{F}_p$.
   So $A$ is conjugate to $\left( \begin{matrix}\xi & * \\ 0 & \xi \end{matrix} \right)$...?
   ( $(p-3) / 2$ matrices are in this case?)
3. The case that $\xi \not= \pm 1$ and $\xi^{p+1} = 1$.
   ...?

From them how can I show the result?

Comment: The approach here is a little different from yours, but maybe [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2955770/understanding-conjugacy-classes-in-sl-2-mathbbf-q?rq=1) could be useful to you?

Comment: Remark. The number of conjugacy classes for $q$ odd is indeed $q+4$. For $q$ even (i.e. a power of $2$), the number of conjugacy classes is instead $q+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the total number of conjugacy classes of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is $q+4$, for any $q=p^n$ an odd prime power.

A reference for the structure of these conjugacy classes can be found in Sections 1.1-1.3 of the text *Representations of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$* by Cedric Bonnafe. All the conjugacy classes are worked out there in detail.

There is a table at the end on page 9 summarizing the four families of conjugacy classes, which contain $2$, $(q-3)/2$, $(q-1)/2$, and $4$ conjugacy classes each.