# Number of conjugacy classes of $sl_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Looking at the group $sl_2(\mathbb{F}_q) $, consisting of $2 \times 2$ matrices with determinant 1 and coefficents in a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ with $q$ elements, I am wondering if there are any general results of the number of conjugacy classes of the group for some $q$?

I've found that, for instance, $sl_2(\mathbb{F}_4)$ has 5 conjugacy classes, using the orbit-stabilizer theorem and the characteristic polynomial, $p_A(\lambda) = \lambda^2 - Tr(A) \lambda + det(A)$, and the results for irreducibility etc, but I have not found a way to generalize this.

Comment: Is [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2955770/understanding-conjugacy-classes-in-sl-2-mathbbf-q?rq=1) helpful? For odd prime power $q$ the number is computed in [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4199720/all-conjugacy-classes-of-operatornamesl-2-mathbbf-p?rq=1), too: "the total number of conjugacy classes of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is $q+4$, for any $q=p^n$ an odd prime power."

Comment: Yes, thank you!